# Не могу понять, почему не все файлы записываються, как html-страницы

Tags: python-3.x, json, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Пишу парсер для сбора данных с metacritic, и сохраняю каждую страницу, как файл в папку дата. Но часть файлов записываются пустыми.

```
url = f'https://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/score/metascore/all/all/filtered=2?page=0'
user_agent = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=user_agent)

src = response.text

with open('index.html',encoding= 'utf-8') as file:
   src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
all_games_hrefs = soup.find_all('a',class_ = 'title')

all_games_dict = {}

for href in all_games_hrefs:
    href_text = href.text
    hrefs = 'https://www.metacritic.com'+href.get('href')
    print(f'{href_text}: {hrefs}')
    all_games_dict[href_text] = hrefs

with open('all_games_hrefs', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(all_games_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

with open('all_games_hrefs') as file:
    all_games = json.load(file)


for game_name, game_href in all_games.items():

    response = requests.get(url=game_href, headers=user_agent)
    src = response.text
    time.sleep(rand.randint(3, 30))
    
    with open(f'data/{game_name}.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(src)

    with open(f'data/{game_name}.html', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        src = file.read()
```

Хотелось бы узнать, с чем это связано и как это можно исправить

Comment: У вас проблемы со словарем all_games_dict. Название игр{href_text} совпадают,  перезаписываются ключи в словаре в цикле. Пример: `print(dict([('GTA', 'https://1'), ('ME', 'https://2'), ('GTA', 'https://3'), ('ME', 'https://4')]))` вывод `{'GTA': 'https://3', 'ME': 'https://4'}`

Comment: @СергейШ, не подскажете, как это лучше исправить?

Comment: используется запрещённые символы в имени файла https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0